# 2022 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/4#questionnaire).**

---

Aviation Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, 2022-10-24](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2022-10-24 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/4). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 5):

Being a moderator means sometimes that for the good of the community you might have to do things with which you disagree. How would you deal with such scenarios?

E.g.: closing questions you would like to keep open (or vice-versa), disagreeing with the outcome of a meta discussion and having to enforce the result.

Answer (score 5):

The site participation has been declining for a while. Do you think this is a problem mods should be invested in solving? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

What do you think a moderator does, and why do you think you can't do the same/enough with the 20k-rep moderation tools?

Answer (score 4):

How would you deal with a highly regarded user that breaks the rules? E.g.: either network ones (see CoC, and being rude to other users) or community made ones (see for example not closing questions that the community agreed would be off-topic here)

Comment: What do you mean by "not closing questions"? Are users required to VTC off-topic posts? If you're talking about users closing their own posts, shouldn't the posts get closed either by five users or by a mod if the community sees it as off topic?

Comment: @Someone I mean people partaking in the review queue and blatantly taking decisions against the community guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Why is Aviation StackExchange important to you?

Answer (score 4):

What one policy already enacted at Aviation StackExchange would you change if you had ultimate power?

Answer (score 3):

On Aviation.SE we have a history of being more liberal with comments than other stacks; in particular we tend to accept jokes in the comment section (if without harm to other users) to leave a valve open for those that would like to be a bit less uptight.

Many users from other SEs will come and flag such comments.

Will you uphold our "traditions" or will you delete such comments?

Answer (score 1):

What is your experience in the field of Aviation, and how do you think this might help you moderate this site?

Answer (score -1):

The mod-only tools have a learning curve, with some outcomes not always fully documented. Are you willing to read and learn about them before jumping in?

Answer (score -3):

Do you believe questions on Aviation SE are closed and reopened correctly?

- How would your approach to question closure be affected by the ability to *'hammer'* a question?
- To what extent do you believe a moderator should be active in closing and reopening questions, given the ability to*'hammer'*?
- To what extent do your personal preferences align with any applicable established policy, and to what extent are you prepared to adjust your practise to align with the consensus?
- Are questions with potential issues taking too long to close, or being closed too quickly? Are questions with edits taking too long to reopen, or being opened too soon?
- Are questions being closed with the correct reasons in the right circumstances, or are there reasons being used too often (when they should not be used but are) or not frequently enough (when they are appropriate but ignored)? Are questions being reopened when inadequate reasoning is identified, or being left to languish?

Comment: Thanks for your input here, but please note the OP specified _"Please only post one question per answer."_ - if you could separate these out that would be great.

Comment: I don't see them as separate questions. Consider the bullet list as optional clarification areas.